# JWT expires immediately in Express and Angular app

Tags: angular, express, jwt, express-jwt

I am using a JSON Web Token in an express and Angular application. I am setting the `expiresIn` property to `30d`, although I understand that is not needed. Whenever I submit a new post through my front-end I get an error that the `jwt expired`. I haven't changed anything regarding this. All I changed was adding a user reference to a post in order to relate a post to a user in MongoDb

Here is my code for the JWT, please let me know if you need to see anything else.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
        const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, "secret_sauce");
        console.log(decodedToken);
        req.userData = {username: decodedToken.username, userId: decodedToken.userId};
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).json({message: 'Auth Failed', error: error});
    }
};
```

Here is a picture of the error:
[image]

Comment: please add the decoded JWT in your question, using https://jwt.io/ for example

Comment: @YoukouleleY there isn't one. looks like it never gets there...

Comment: @YoukouleleY Forget what I said before. It does get to the check-auth intercepter that I have but falls through to the `catch` part. I've updated the post to show the full code for the intercepter